# How to fix Type error: Object is of type 'unknown'?

Tags: typescript, types, next.js

Code:
const CategoryDropdownSidebar = () => {
const {data, isLoading: loading, error } = useCategoriesQuery({
type: "grocery",
});

```
  return (
    <aside className="sticky top-22 h-full lg:w-72 hidden xl:block bg-white">
      <div className="max-h-full overflow-hidden">
        <Scrollbar className="w-full h-full max-h-screen">
          {data?.categories?.data?.length ? (
            <div className="px-5">
              <SidebarMenu items={data?.categories?.data} className="py-8" />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="min-h-full pt-6 pb-8 px-9 lg:p-8">
              <NotFound text="Sorry, No Category Found :(" className="h-96" />
            </div>
          )}
        </Scrollbar>
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
};
```

[image: error]

[image]

Face an error on the build but the dev server is okay.

https://pastebin.com/S4uWQsjp

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code and errors as text, not as images.

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: facing error when add code

Comment: Seems useCategoriesQuery hook returns untyped `data` property. YOu should write return type for your hook